# Nested data access in React.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested, ecmascript-6, redux

I have list of videos that have a list of images. I want to change the images on hover. I have created an activeImgSrcId to keep track of the active image. video.imgList has a list of images. video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId] fetches me the required url when I put a debug point. However after removing the debug point, I see

```
Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

This is my render method

```
renderVideoList() {
    return this.props.videoLibrary.map(video => (
      <div className="col-md-4" key={video.id}>
        <Link to={`videos/${video.id}`}>
          <img
            src={video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId]} 
          />
        </Link>
      </div>
      ));
  }
```

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to access this kind of nested structure?

Comment: what's the result of printing `this.props`?

Comment: How about calling `renderVideoList()` only if `this.props.videoLibrary && (this.props.videoLibrary.length === true)`? Additionally you could return `null` in the inline function if not all required attributes of video are defined.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the issue that your prop `videoLibrary` may be null at the time of rendering.
Better initialize `videoLibrary` with empty array if data fetched from server asynchronously and when data is available pass the updated props to your component.

or

```
renderVideoList() {
    return (this.props.videoLibrary||[]).map(video => (
      <div className="col-md-4" key={video.id}>
        <Link to={`videos/${video.id}`}>
          <img
            src={video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId]} 
          />
        </Link>
      </div>
      ));
  }
```

Comment: @havenchyk I have given alternative option as well. Btw if array is empty do you think map will be executed at all?

Comment: sorry, I had intention to add a comment to another post :D

Comment: @havenchyk no problem :)

Comment: @WitVault I tried all the three solutions. None of them worked. if I add `src={video.activeImgSrcId}` I dont get an error. Can we access arrays like this `video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId]` in react?

Comment: @WitVault I found the issue. In some of the data video.activeImgSrcId is not present. Hence it is breaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As **@WItVault** already posted, `videoLibrary` can be null or even undefined. So you need to add a check for it

```
renderVideoList() {
  const videoLibrary = this.props.videoLibrary

  if (!videoLibrary) return

  return videoLibrary.map(video => (
    <div className="col-md-4" key={video.id}>
      <Link to={`videos/${video.id}`}>
        <img
          src={video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId]} 
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

I prefer early return, you don't need to run `map` on empty array with it.
If you're okay with multiple return statements in function, you can use such approach.

Comment: I tried all the three solutions. None of them worked. if I add `src={video.activeImgSrcId}` I dont get an error. Can we access arrays like this `video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId]` in react?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that the prop `videoLibrary` is not available with initial render and hece you should provide a check for it. A check can be as easy as below before the `map` function

```
renderVideoList() {
    return  this.props.videoLibrary && this.props.videoLibrary.map(video => (
      <div className="col-md-4" key={video.id}>
        <Link to={`videos/${video.id}`}>
          <img
            src={video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId]} 
          />
        </Link>
      </div>
      ));
  }
```

Comment: you was the third one, please read other answers before posting the same

Comment: @havenchyk was the same suggestion but the method was different

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I tried all the three solutions. None of them worked. if I add `src={video.activeImgSrcId}` I dont get an error. Can we access arrays like this `video.imgList[video.activeImgSrcId]` in react?